# Convert timestamp to epoch Pentaho PDI 8 CE

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

I want to convert a timestamp `2019/02/12 00:00:00.000` into Epoch time `1549486845`.

I see many posts about doing the opposite conversion, but how can you convert it from timestamp to epoch?

Pentaho PDI 8 CE

Answer (score 2):

I just used a `Select Values` step which convert the timestamp field to integer and then it is divided by 1000 in an `User defined Java Expression`.

Comment: Works on PDI 7.0 CE as well.